# AWS simple Crud operation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS. for initial understanding i need..
full flow from Angularjs(which i know) -> api gateway(i know) -> lambda(node.js) -> dynamodb.

i am looking for simple CRUD operation samples. i know how to write code in Angular, APIGateway but struggling out with Lambda(Node.js) for writing code that can perform CRUD operation on dynamodb Table.
can any one please provide link or sample project which contain sample code in node.js. (i have googled it a lot but couldnt find out straight away samples) i am also following aws document site. but i feel its slightly complex or i am stupid :) )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [example project](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels-lambda) which shows how to use [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) (a DynamoDB data mapper for nodejs) with lambda. Currently, the project just has a single function which writes data to a DynamoDB table, but would be easy to add more CRUD functions.